# Special charectors are not storing in react usecookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I'm trying to store tokens using react useCookie, but it's not allowing me to store any special characters. [![

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookie-name']);
const authCtx = useContext(authContext);

  const onEmailVarification = async () => {
    // const response = userService.emailVarification();
    const _token = "132|efsc5d48ffff557f65f8f";
    setCookie('cookie-name', _token, { path: '/' });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: `%7C` is the pipe character encoded. Did you try to read it back before you determined it wasn't stored?

Comment: yes, But it's working on document.cookie = "token=132|efsc5d48ffff557f65f8f";
but specifically doesn't work on useCookie package

Comment: It specifically does very much so: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jones-o12njm?file=/src/App.js (because the library uses encoding to make sure that even special characters are stored, and it converts back to the original string when you read the token). Which you didn't check like I asked